# Solving 6 equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I'm working on one privacy-preserving cryptographic protocol that both parties try to compute one function with their private inputs.

If one party is trying to guess the other party's inputs then she should solve about 6 nonlinear equations with 6 variables ($a,b,c,w,y,z$).

Since those variables are representing the latitude and longitude of some coordinates, I'm looking for solutions in integers and real numbers.
Here is one example:

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
ab+wy-2a-2b-2w-2y=-13\\
ay-bw+2b-2a+2w-2y=15\\
bc+yz-2b-2c-2y-2z=-18\\
bz-cy+2c-2b+2y-2z=5\\
ca+zw-2c-2a-2z-2w=-9\\
cw-az+2a-2c+2z-2w=7
\end{array}\right\}$$

but I don't know how can I solve this system of equations. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you looking for solutions in the integers, rationals, reals, complex numbers, or elsewhere?

Comment: I'm looking for solutions in the integers, rationals, and reals.

Comment: $$a=\frac{1}{5} \left(-3 \sqrt{-b^2+4 b+21}-b+12\right)$$

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: My result agrees with yours. There are infinitely many real solutions $(a,b,c,w,y,z)$, and in fact, here are infinitely many rational solutions $(a,b,c,w,y,z)$.

Comment: @quasi Did you use Maple?

Comment: @I'm a student: Yes, I used Maple's Groebner basis package.

Comment: @quasi Could you tell me at least one set of answers?

Comment: @Mandana Ghasemi: Here's one solution:
$$a=3,\;\;b=6,\;\;c=-1/5,\;\;w=-1,\;\;y=5,\;\;z=8/5$$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82237/discussion-on-question-by-mandana-ghasemi-solving-6-equations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt to find all real solutions.  Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $W$, $Y$, and $Z$ denote $a-2$, $b-2$, $c-2$, $w-2$, $y-2$, and $z-2$, respectively.  We have
$$AB+WY=-5\,,$$
$$AY-BW=15\,,$$
$$BC+YZ=-10\,,$$
$$BZ-CY=5\,,$$
$$CA+ZW=-1\,,$$
and
$$CW-AZ=7\,.$$
Write $P:=A+W\text{i}$, $Q:=B+Y\text{i}$, and $R:=C+Z\text{i}$.  Then, 
$$\bar{P}Q=-5+15\text{i}\,,$$
$$\bar{Q}R=-10+5\text{i}\,,$$
and
$$\bar{R}P=-1+7\text{i}\,.$$
From here, it is easily seen that $|P|=\sqrt{10}$, $|Q|=5$, and $|R|=\sqrt{5}$.  Letting $P=\sqrt{10}\,u$, where $u\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|u|=1$, we get
$$Q=5\,\left(\frac{-1+3\text{i}}{\sqrt{10}}\right)\,\bar{u}$$
and
$$R=\sqrt{5}\,\left(\frac{-1-7\text{i}}{5\sqrt{2}}\right)\,\bar{u}\,.$$
If $u=\cos(t)+\text{i}\sin(t)$, then
$$P=\sqrt{10}\,\cos(t)+\text{i}\,\sqrt{10}\,\sin(t)\,,$$
$$Q=5\,\left(\frac{-\cos(t)+3\,\sin(t)}{\sqrt{10}}\right)+\text{i}\,5\,\left(\frac{3\,\cos(t)+\sin(t)}{\sqrt{10}}\right)$$
and
$$R=\sqrt{5}\,\left(\frac{-\cos(t)-7\,\sin(t)}{5\sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{i}\,\sqrt{5}\,\left(\frac{-7\,\cos(t)+\sin(t)}{5\sqrt{2}}\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$a=A+2=\text{Re}(P)+2=\sqrt{10}\,\cos(t)+2\,,$$
$$b=B+2=\text{Re}(Q)+2=5\,\left(\frac{-\cos(t)+3\,\sin(t)}{\sqrt{10}}\right)+2\,,$$
$$c=C+2=\text{Re}(R)+2=\sqrt{5}\,\left(\frac{-\cos(t)-7\,\sin(t)}{5\sqrt{2}}\right)+2\,,$$
$$w=W+2=\text{Im}(P)+2=\sqrt{10}\,\sin(t)+2\,,$$
$$y=Y+2=\text{Im}(Q)+2=5\,\left(\frac{3\,\cos(t)+\sin(t)}{\sqrt{10}}\right)+2\,,$$
and
$$z=Z+2=\text{Im}(R)+2=\sqrt{5}\,\left(\frac{-7\,\cos(t)+\sin(t)}{5\sqrt{2}}\right)+2\,.$$
There are indeed infinitely many real solutions, but they form a circle in $\mathbb{R}^6$ centered at $(a,b,c,w,y,z)=(2,2,2,2,2,2)$ with radius $\sqrt{10+25+5}=2\sqrt{10}$.  In other words,
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\w\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\\2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}10\\-5\\-1\\0\\15\\-7\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{10}}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\15\\-7\\10\\5\\1\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{10}}$$
for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, which is contained in the $2$-dimensional affine plane 
$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\\2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}+\text{span}_\mathbb{R}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}10\\-5\\-1\\0\\15\\-7\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\15\\-7\\10\\5\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}\,.$$

---

If you want to find rational solutions, then the task is to solve for rational numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2+q^2=10$.  First, note that $(p,q)=(1,3)$ is a solution.  Any other solution except $(p,q)=(1,-3)$ must satisfy $q-3=r\,(p-1)$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.  Plug this in to get
$$p^2+\big(r\,(p-1)^2+3\big)^2=10\,,$$
or
$$(p-1)\,\big(r^2\,(p-1)+6\,r+(p+1)\big)=0\,.$$
Thus, $p=1$ or
$$p=\frac{r^2-6\,r-1}{r^2+1}=1-2\,\left(\frac{3r+1}{r^2+1}\right)\,.$$
This means $q=3$ or
$$q=3-2\,\left(\frac{r(3r+1)}{r^2+1}\right)\,.$$
Note that $r=-\dfrac13$ already gives $(p,q)=(1,3)$, so there is no need to treat this case separately.  The only point that is included in this parametrization is $(p,q)=(1,-3)$.  However, the parametrization
$$(p,q)=\Biggl(1-2\,\left(\frac{3r+1}{r^2+1}\right),3-2\,\left(\frac{r(3r+1)}{r^2+1}\right)\Biggr)$$
already includes $(p,q)=(1,-3)$ if we take $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$.
  That is, the rational solutions $(a,b,c,w,y,z)\in\mathbb{Q}^6$ satisfy 
$$\small\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\w\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\\2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}10\\-5\\-1\\0\\15\\-7\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{1}{10}\,\Biggl(1-2\,\left(\frac{3r+1}{r^2+1}\right)\Biggr)+\begin{bmatrix}0\\15\\-7\\10\\5\\1\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{1}{10}\,\Biggl(3-2\,\left(\frac{r(3r+1)}{r^2+1}\right)\Biggr)$$
for some $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: one questions..If we assume that (a,w) (b,y) and (c,z) are Cartesian coordinates, then the equations still have infinite answers?

Comment: I don't understand the question though.  If you are talking about that I use complex numbers (i.e., write $A+W\text{i}$, for example, in the polar form $\sqrt{10}\,\exp(\text{i}t)$), then the work will be no different if you avoid the polar form, except being more cumbersome to deal with.  So, if this is what you meant, then yes, there will still be infinitely many answers.

Comment: @Batominovski, why did you answer the question then vote to close it?  So that no one else can answer it?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche  I voted to close it at first because the OP's question did not come with typed question.  There was a photo, which was very dark, and I couldn't read it.  When the OP clarified, I simply forgot to retract the closed vote.  Look at the edit history so you will know what I am talking about.  And if you notice, there is one reopen vote.  That is my vote.  I couldn't care less about reputation points, or whether my answer is the only one, or whether my answer is accepted.  In fact, I prefer diversity of answers.  If I close vote some questions, I have a very good reason.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Furthermore, I don't see anything wrong if an answerer decides to close the question to which the answerer gave an answer.  The answerer may have many good reasons to close the thread.  For example, the answerer may feel that the asker has not spent enough effort, would not listen to any clarification to the errors in the question, make some late changes in the question that render the answerer's response irrelevant, is rude to the answerer, etc.  Those are valid reasons to close a thread.  There is no need for an accusatory tone to an answerer who decides to close a question.

Comment: @Batominovski  btw, I don't think so that solving 6 nonlinear equations can be considered as an off-topic question for this site!!. I'm a new member and it was the first time that I posted my question and asking for help. After posting my question for less than one minute all equations appeared in one dark picture and after that one member solved the problem. Even I was answering all the questions regarding clarifying the question. I don't think voting as an off-topic is fair.

Comment: @MandanaGhasemi  Oh, I voted to close because of the dark picture, and forgot to retract the vote when the equations were given in text.  However, other members voted to close for most likely the reason that you did not show the effort.  I usually don't vote to close questions that are sufficiently difficult, and certainly, I consider your question to be ok.  I can't say the same for other users.  "Off-topic" closure can often mean that the asker does not show sufficient effort in solving the problem.  Unfortunately, it is not unfair.  This system is made so that askers make some attempts.

Comment: @Batominovski yeah, you are right but in some type of questions, the asker doesn't have any idea about solving the problem. As I'm not a mathematician I have knowledge about solving a linear system of equations but I didn't know about the nonlinear system. Btw, you answered my question in a very nice way and I learned a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @MandanaGhasemi That's why I don't close-vote questions I deem sufficiently difficult.  But other users do not share my belief.  Heck, sometimes they even close threads in which askers show some attempts, simply because the attempts are somehow insufficient.